# Making time(0) produce an error

Tags: linux, hardware, ubuntu, c, time

I'm currently reviewing/reversing a software (coded in C) and it has a line like this :

`time_t var = time(0);`

My goal it to get this time(0) call to return -1.
(I cannot modify the parameter.)

Looking for any hints/POC methods to achieve this, with a high preference for solutions which do not require root perms. But I'd be happy to hear root solutions as well. So far I've tried to modify the system's clock, but I can't manage to set it to a value that would make time fail. (Btw hardware manipulation solutions are also welcomed)

Context :

- System environment : Ubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit.

Comment: You could write your own implementation of `time`, compile it into a library and use `LD_PRELOAD` to load it and use it instead of the original implementation.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/zardus/preeny/blob/master/src/detime.c